# Are there any PC to phone programs that supplies you a free phone number?

Tags: communication

I read [this](http://freebies.about.com/od/computerfreebies/tp/free-internet-phone-calls.htm), but none appear to supply you a unique phone number free (of charge)?

Comment: You should add some more criteria. For example which country you want the number to be hosted in

Comment: Your question needs more details. What is a pc to phone program?

Comment: What is "this"? What exactly do you need – features, price, OS, etc? Please see [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) and [edit] your question accordingly. Currently it doesn't hold enough details to give good recommendations.

Comment: for some "background"-info to make somethings a little bit clearer, maybe read this: [VoIP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice_over_IP) and [SIP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_Initiation_Protocol)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try Google Voice, www.google.com/voice. I'm not trying to sell you something but IZZY deleted my post because it did not contain enough details. Here are more details:

Google Voice gives you one number for all your phones, voicemail as easy as email, free US long distance, low rates on international calls, etc.

Features
[image]

https://www.google.com/googlevoice/about.html

Comment: IZZY deleted your comment now as well – but undeleted your answer. A simple flag on it, and I had noticed earlier :) Thanks for the update!